# How can I solve this system of nonlinear PDEs?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, nonlinear

How can I solve these PDE analytically for $z$ and $y$?

\begin{eqnarray}
2 \dot{z} &=&  \ddot{y}+ y^{-1}, ~~~ (1)\\
 z' + \dot{z}' &=& - \dot{y}'. ~~~~~~~~~~ (2)
\end{eqnarray}

Where (.) is the time derivative ($\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ ) and (’) is the derivative with respect to `x` : ($\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$).

Here is my trial:

```
eq1[x_, t_] = 2*D[z[t, x], t] == D[y[x, t], {t, 2}] + y[x, t]^(-1); 

eq2[x_, t_] = D[z[t, x], x] + D[D[z[t, x], t], x] == -D[D[y[x, t], t], x]; 

DSolve[{eq1[x, t], eq2[x, t]}, {z[t, x], y[x, t]}, {t, x}]
```

But `DSolve` dose not give a solution.

**Edit**

I try to eliminate `z` from the second equation, using the first equation. So any help to make these steps?

- Integrate (1) to get `z(x, t)`: To do so, I use:

  ```
  Integrate[ D[y[x, t], {t, 2}] + y[x, t]^(-1), y[x, t], t]
  ```

But I don't understand the output:

```
Out[1]=Integrate[Log[y[x, t]], t] + y[x, t]*Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t]
```

-Then differentiate `z(x, t)` with respect to `x` to get  `z’(x,t)`.

- Differentiate  (1) with respect to `x` to get $\dot{z}’$
- Then substitute by $z’$ and  $\dot{z}’$ in (2)

**Edit:2**

I tried to solve

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac{\dot{y}^2}{2}+\log (y)\right) =2 \dot{y}\  \dot{z}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial (y+z)}{\partial t}+z=\text{C1}(t)$$

In MA by:

```
eq1[x, t] := D[D[y[x, t], t]^2/2 + Log[y[x, t]], t] -2*D[y[x, t], t]*D[z[x, t], t]

eq2[x, t] := D[y[x, t] + z[x, t], t] + z[x, t] - c

DSolveValue[{eq1[x, t] == eq2[x, t] == 0, y[x, 0] == 0, z[x, 0]
   == 0}, {y[x, t], z[x, t]}, {x, t}]
```

With or without initial conditions, or by using `DSolve` , there is no output solution.

Comment: These can't be easily solved because they are nonlinear. You also are mixing arguments. You write `z[t, x]` then in the call to `DSolve` you write `z[x, t]`. Strange that you did not see this error from `DSolve`  Also your latex is confusing. This is not how partial derivatives are written in Latex.

Comment: Hello @Nasser. Yes, it’s not easy solving, also I have tried `Reduce`. I edit the question to make the partial derivatives clear in the latex equations.

Comment: Why are they nonlinear? Because they contain $y^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that makes the system nonlinear.

Comment: The 2nd equation can be integrated over x analytically, which might simplify the solution

Comment: @HansOlo. Hi, I thought to eliminate one of the variables `z` or `y` and make a single equation in one variable.

Comment: @HansOlo. Can you please look at the question’s edit?

Answer (score 4):

It seems doubtful to me that a symbolic general solution exists.  However, a symbolic particular solution can be obtained without difficulty.  Suppose that `z[x, t] = 0`.  Then, equ2 can be dropped, and equ1 (which almost certainly is independent of `x`) integrated.

```
DSolve[D[y[t], {t, 2}] + y[t]^(-1) == 0, y[t], t] // Flatten
(* {y[t] -> E^(1/2 (C[1] - 2 InverseErf[-Sqrt[2/Pi] Sqrt[E^-C[1] (t + C[2])^2]]^2)), 
    y[t] -> E^(1/2 (C[1] - 2 InverseErf[Sqrt[2/Pi] Sqrt[E^-C[1] (t + C[2])^2]]^2))} *)
```

**Addendum: Convert PDE pair into single ODE**

Consider the two PDEs.

```
eq1 = 2*D[z[x, t], t] == D[y[x, t], {t, 2}] + y[x, t]^-1
eq2 = z[x, t] + D[z[x, t], t] == c[t] - D[y[x, t], t]
```

(`eq2` here is the first-integral of `eq2` in the question, as derived by RolandF in another answer to the question.  It is valid, provided that `y` and `z` actually do depend on `x`.  `c[t]` is an unknown function of `t` only, resulting from the integration.)  Because `z` enters only linearly in both PDEs, it can be eliminated between the two as follows.

```
eq1 /. Solve[eq2, D[z[x, t], t]] // Flatten;
fr = Solve[%, z[x, t]] // Flatten

(* {z[x, t] -> (-1 + 2*c[t]*y[x, t] - 2*y[x, t]*D[y[x, t], t] - 
                y[x, t]*D[y[x, t], t, t]) / (2*y[x, t])} *)
```

With `z` now given in terms of `y`, it can be eliminated from `eq2`.

```
eq2 /. z -> Function[{x, t}, Evaluate[fr[[1, 2]]]] // Simplify;
eq3 = MultiplySides[%, y[x, t], Assumptions -> y[x, t] != 0] // Simplify

(* D[y[x, t], t] + y[x, t]^2*(2*c'[t] - 3*D[y[x, t], t, t] 
   - D[y[x, t], t, t, t]) == y[x, t] *)
```

Since `x` enters only as a parameter, the pair of PDEs has indeed been reduced to a single ODE.  Unfortunately, `DSolve` cannot integrate this ODE either.  As a final attempt, I converted `eq3` to a second-order ODE, which is possible for constant `c`, because `eq3` is autonomous (i.e., `t` does not enter explicitly.  The resulting second-order ODE (for c[t] = 0), obtained by replacing `y'[t]` by w[y] and ignoring the parameter `x`, is

```
w[y] + y^2 (-3 w'[y] w[y] - w''[y] w[y]^2 - w'[y]^2 w[y]) == y
```

It too cannot be integrated by `DSolve`.

Comment: Hello @bbgodfrey. Thanks for your answer.  But `z[x, t]` can not equal zero.

Comment: Could `z` be a constant or dependent only on `t`?  Could your `C1[t]` be a constant?  Any information that could narrow the range of possible solutions would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much @bbgodfrey for your solution. This is exactly what I thought about a single DE in `y`. But how MA can solve this? . `C1[t]` can vanish, since the initial conditions can be chosen so that the integration constants vanish. But still `z` and `y` functions of `[x, t]` . I think this term `D[y[x, t], t, t, t]` is the problem, also I wonder can `DSolve` or `AsympotiticDSolveValue` solve something like `DSolve[eq, {z[x, t] ,y[x, t]}, {x, t}]` , if not,  I think one can find the numeric solution first, then find the analytic expressions by fitting.

Comment: @Dr.phy, I am confident that DSolve cannot solve your equations, even if` `C1[t]` vanishes.  In fact, I doubt that a symbolic solution even exists.  A symbolic asymptotic or power series solution probably does exist, at least for most starting points.  A numerical solution requires three boundary conditions in `t`.  Provide them, and I can see what I can do.

Answer (score 3):

Most what one can do is using the energy trick for the first equation

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac{\dot{y}^2}{2}+\log (y)\right) =2 \dot{y}\  \dot{z}$$
and finding a first integral of the second
$$\frac{\partial (y+z)}{\partial t}+z=\text{C1}(t)$$

Comment: Hello @Roland F. Thanks for your answer, but how with these two equations get `z` or `y`?

Comment: Can you please look at the question's edit:2? @Roland F.

Comment: For such an algebraically transparent equation, I don't see a solution. Partial differential equations represent examples from wave  field theories, harmonic function theories and diffusion of matter. Quadratic time derivative sugests a wave equation,  two components suggest a change of the components of a separated wave equation into a radial part y and a circualr wave in z. Give the origin of the equation, perhaps it comes with a Solve strategy.  System PDE's without boundary and start conditions,  solution spaces predefined by function norms don't form solvable problem classes .

Comment: Even without Mathematica, can't the first equation in your answer be integrated as:  $ \int \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac{\dot{y}^2}{2}+\log (y)\right) =2 \int \dot{y}\  \dot{z} = \left(\frac{\dot{y}^2}{2}+\log (y)\right) =2  z ~\dot{y}  $.      Is that  correct?

Comment: No, the product of two derivatives yields at best $$\int \partial_t y \partial_t z dt =y \partial_t z- \int y \partial_{t,t} z dt$$

Comment: Integration by parts twice of $ \dot{z} \dot{y} dt $ yields : $ \int \dot{z} \dot{y} dt = y \dot{z} - ( y \dot{z} - \int \dot{z} \dot{y} dt )$ , is that means $ \int \dot{z} \dot{y} dt =0 $?